# Sparql insert data not working

Tags: insert, sparql, semantic-web

I'm a newbie to Sparql, but I am unable even to make a simple insert data query, or so it seems.

I'm using Apache Fuseki as working server; I'm in a graph, and I'm trying to make this query work:

```
PREFIX oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

INSERT DATA{             
  [ a 
    oa:Annotation ;                    
    rdfs:label "Title";                    
  ] .                    
}
```

But it doesn't matter what I do, I keep getting this error:

> Error 400: SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter

This is even a semplified code, I tried many queries even more complex, but the result doesn't change...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SPARQL, query and update are different operations.  In Fuseki, they reside on different endpoints (so query can be be more widely accessible than update).

You are calling the query endpoint (`.../query` or `.../sparql` usually) ; you need to call the update (`.../update`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error with your turtle in the SPARQL update

instead of

```
  [ a 
    oa:Annotation ;                    
    rdfs:label "Title";                    
  ] .
```

use

```
  [ a 
    oa:Annotation ;                    
    rdfs:label "Title"                    
  ] .
```

Comment: The first form is legal syntax though better (?) not written that way.  It's legal in Turtle as well. http://www.sparql.org/update-validator.html

Comment: Going by the example here http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#BNodes , but you are right