# Jena Fuseki Sparql No query= error

Tags: rdf, fuseki, apache-jena

I am trying to inset data in a jena fuseki graph using this simple query:

```
PREFIX test: <http://test.org> 
INSERT {?subject test:hasName "Bob"} 
WHERE{
  ?subject test:hasEmail "email@test.com" .
}
```

However, i get the error:
Error 400: SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter

Fuseki - version 2.3.1 (Build date: 2015-12-08T09:24:07+0000)

What does this error mean, and how can i resolve it?  this error also appear when i try to delete data. Thanks.

Comment: How are you querying the triple store? This seems an HTTP request error (you are missing the `query` parameter).

Comment: @Giuseppe Marra I am using the query tab in jena fuseki. That is why the error is strange, unless the gui is sending sparql queries as a get request to itself...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309632/sparql-insert-data-not-working and check which endpoint are you currently querying

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309632/sparql-insert-data-not-working that @GiuseppeMarra linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are pointing at the appropriate endpoint.
In Fuseki the queries endpoint (for example, **http://localhost:13030/mygraph/query**) is different than the update endpoint (**http://localhost:13030/mygraph/update**).

Selects, asks and constructs should be done using the first one, while updates, inserts and deletes should be done using the second one.