# DELETE QUERY SPARQL FUSEKI

Tags: web, sparql, rdfs, fuseki

How can I delete all triples statement for a given uri?

My graph contains:

```
 PREFIX mo: <http://www.dbwic.org/ontology#> 
          PREFIX term:  <http://www.dbwic.org/ontology/terms/>
          PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
 <http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a> term:title "tiitle album";
                                                                  term:date "date title";
                                                                  term:name " name ".
```

I tried to delete all triples for http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a but the query is not working.

```
 PREFIX mo: <http://www.dbwic.org/ontology#> 
          PREFIX term:  <http://www.dbwic.org/ontology/terms/>
          PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
delete{  ?id ?p ?o}
where
    {   
     FILTER (?id = <http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a>)
    ?id ?p ?o
    }
```

SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter (#400)
Error 400: SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter

Comment: The problem is within your SPARQL service HTTP URL resp. the Fuseki config. Please show both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jena Fuseki Sparql No query= error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451715/jena-fuseki-sparql-no-query-error)

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE WHERE 
{ <http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a> ?p ?o }`

but your problem is this:

```
SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter
```

It looks like you are sending an update to the query endpoint.

The update and query endpoints are separate.

Check the code used to send the update request.  It usually is called "update":

```
http://host:port/*YourDataset*/update
```

The query endpoint ends `.../query` or `.../sparql`.

Answer (score 2):

I really can't help with Fuseki, but I wanted to point out that you have a SPARQL anti-pattern here.  The where clause does not need a FILTER.  I.e. replace

```
{
   FILTER  (?id = <http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a>)
  ?id ?p ?o
}
```

...with the BGP (Basic Graph Pattern)

```
{
   <http://www.dbwic.org/page/d2e2e606-f962-4db1-8ffc-883e75da109a> ?p ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are pointing at the appropriate endpoint. In Fuseki the queries endpoint

for example `(http://localhost:3030/mydataset/query)` is different than the update endpoint `(http://localhost:3030/mydataset/update)`.

Selects, asks and constructs should be done using the first one, while updates, inserts and deletes should be done using the second one.

Comment: this is the correct answer, in the fuseki web gui, above the request, there is a field: `SPARQL endpoint` which by default is `/mydataset/query` that you should channge to `/mydataset/update` .