# Java how use sparql Delete query

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, fuseki, apache-jena

I need some help removing an entry from my `fuseki server`

For example, how can I remove this entry?

```
<http://person/Test1>
    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/name> "Test1" ;
```

This is what I've tried, but it's not working...

```
public void deletePerson(String[] personalData ) {
        String personURI    = "http://localhost:3030/Date";
        String name = personalData[0];
        String query = "DELETE WHERE { <http://person/" + formattedName + "> }";
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                "http://localhost:3030/Date/query",
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> " + query);
    }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered "  "DELETE WHERE "" at line 1, column 47.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       "base" ...
>       "prefix" ...
>       "select" ...
>       "describe" ...
>       "construct" ...
>       "ask" ...

Comment: Here is example of the same problem how to untie it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620588/delete-query-sparql-fuseki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DELETE QUERY SPARQL FUSEKI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620588/delete-query-sparql-fuseki)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use UpdateExecutionFactory
Something like that

```
 UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(queryString) ;
            UpdateProcessor proc = UpdateExecutionFactory.create(request, graphStore) ;
```

Comment: like this : 

 String name = personalData[0];
String query = "DELETE WHERE { <http://person/" + formattedName + "> }";
UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(query);

UpdateExecutionFactory
          .createRemote(request, "http://localhost:3030/Date/query",
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> ");

Comment: "It's not working" is **not** meaningful! What does not work? And a bit of Java skills have to be provided by yourself - documentation is here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/update.html And by the way, you sample code does not work, you have a Java object `name` but use an unknown Java object `formattedName` - that's for sure wrong.

Comment: I can't help with the code but an update isn't going to work against the query  endpoint anyway. It's probably http://localhost:3030/Date/update but check the config file to be sure.