# How to Sparql INSERT in TopBraid Composer?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, rdfs, topbraid-composer

I'm trying to insert new classes by using Sparql in TopBraid Composer (ME 5.5.2). My simple ontology looks like this:

[image]

Then I wrote a Sparql query to insert `Berry` as a subclass of `Fruit`:

```
PREFIX ft: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2018/7/fruit#>
PREFIX rdfs: <ttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

INSERT
{ft:Berry    rdfs:subClassOf  ft:Fruit}
```

But an error message appeared, saying `Encountered "insert". Was expecting one of: "base, "select", ...`

A similar post: [Sparql insert data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309632/sparql-insert-data-not-working) says that Sparql Query is a different language from Sparql Update. Some other post says that Sparql Update is not supported in Protege but is supported in Composer (for which reason I downloaded Composer). I also checked the Composer manual: https://www.topquadrant.com/docs/TBC-Getting-Started-Guide52.pdf, which mentions Sparql Update but doesn't say much.

My question then is, is it possible to insert classes and axioms in TopBraid? If so, how? My end goal is that the inserted classes will appear in the hierarchical view, and their inserted class definitions can be seen on the side as well. If Composer can't do this, what other tools/workflows can I use?

Sorry for such a newbie question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `INSERT DATA` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I tried `INSERT DATA`. There were red lines under `ft:Berry`and `ft:Fruit`. I right-clicked on them, and the only options it gave are `Reset to empty SELECT query` and `RESET to empty CONSTRUCT query`. Seems like it's still not happy about `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two forms of `INSERT` in SPARQL 1.1 Update:

- [`INSERT DATA`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData)
- [`INSERT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insert)

You are mixing them up.

The following works for me in TBC 5.5.2 Free Edition against the `kennedys.ttl` example:

```
INSERT DATA
    { kennedys:UralStateUniversity a kennedys:College }
```

Being an unknown URI, the subject is underlined in query editor, but just press the "Execute SPARQL" button.

**Update**

In your particular case, you should say something like

```
INSERT DATA
    { ft:Berry rdfs:subClassOf ft:Fruit; a owl:Class }
```

Please note that `owl:Class` is used. TBC considers instances of `rdfs:Class` as "system classes", their icons are brown, not yellow.

Comment: I tried that, and it does work! I was able to see the update in the change history. Thank you! One follow-up question: Does this mean your original ontology is modified? What should I do to make it appear in the hierarchy in the Class view?

Comment: I finally got the display working! Also successfully displayed class definitions, as a result of a long `INSERT` query. Thank you very very much!